# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Tags: reactjs, forms, axios, mern

I have this code and it the result is Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

My create account function is giving me this error

```
const sendRequest = async () => {
    if (!name || !email || !password) return;
    const user = { name, email, password };
    const res = await axios
      .post('/api/v1/auth/register', {
        user,
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    const data = await res.data;
    return data;
  };

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    sendRequest().then(() => setMloggi(true));
};
```

Comment: can u show what is the value of `res`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the respnse result might be an error. Hence it's not returning a data property. Check if data exists and no need to await again

```
 if(res.data)
    return data;

 return [] // or an object. whatever the standard response
```

also, no need to use `then` here since the result is already resolved

```
const result = sendRequest()
if(result) setMloggi(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I suggest using `try catch` block instead of `.then`,`.catch` while using `async await`.
2. Getting `TypeError` because access something in `res` which doesn't exist

```js
const sendRequest = async () => {
  if (!name || !email || !password) return;
  const user = { name, email, password };
  try {
    const res = await axios.post("/api/v1/auth/register", {
      user,
    });
   const data = await res?.data ;
   return data ?? "not found";
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```